# Android code to send http request to a local server

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection, iot

I have implemented HttpUrlConnection to send a request to a local http server (common LAN,Wifi,WifiAP). The code works perfectly fine for normal web servers (www.xyz.com), but fails to do so for local servers (192.168.x.y:z).

The code:

1) The function which makes the request

```
public static String getDef(String urlInput) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://" + urlInput);
            Log.d("http", "calling " + url.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.connect();
            InputStream in = null;
            in = (conn.getInputStream());
            String response =readIt(in,5) ;
            //response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("http","Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "LocalClient didnt work";
    }
```

2) The function which calls the above function.

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>(){
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
    try {
        return LocalClient.getDef(URL);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
    return "Didnt work";
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
    message.append(string);
}
}.execute();
```

3)The request is received at the server with the following headers.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LYZ28E)
Host: 192.168.0.101
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

It would be wonderful if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have also tried OkHttp,

```
public static String get(String url) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        try {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            resp= response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

On using a normal webserver the response is properly returned (source) but while using a local server I get the following error

```
java.io.EOFException
         W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:95)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:179)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:101)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:628)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.demo.demo.http.LocalClient.getDef(LocalClient.java:56)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.demo.demo.wifi.connector$2$2.doInBackground(connector.java:109)
         W/System.err﹕ at com.demo.demo.wifi.connector$2$2.doInBackground(connector.java:105)
         W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
         W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
         W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
         W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
         W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
         W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: "fails to do so"? What happens? What is different between the result with a local and a remote server?

Comment: Hey there! I've also been facing a similar issue. It would be great if someone could point out what we're doing wrong.

Comment: How do you set urlInput for local server? "localhost"?

Comment: @selalerer I have edited my question. Remote server returns the source of the webpage while local server throws an error; but the request is received at the local server.

Comment: @BNK I have tried  http://192.168.0.101, http://192.168.0.101:80 and http://192.168.0.101:80//

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the server, not writing the correct Content-Length thus making the client read after the response ended.

Comment: to me it looks like the local server is terminating the tcp connection

Comment: EOFException, IMO you should check response code first. If 200(OK), getInputStream(). If others(error), getErrorStream() instead. Hope this helps

Comment: @selalerer You are right. The code works for local Mercury server's page. ( OkHttp doesn't work for that too).

Can you shed some light on the issue? On how the response headers are supposed to be set in the text. I am using Lua and I am not aware of any functions to do so.

Comment: Hi! As I commented above, you should use getErrorStream() to get detail error message from the local web server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was server-side and was resolved by using appropriate headers.
OkHttp still doesn't seem to work and the function "public static String getDef(String urlInput)" mentioned above works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's an open bug about this issue:
https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1518

They suggest adding `android:vmSafeMode="true"` to the manifest file.